# Linux, postgres, copy command result in error with file permissions

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-copy

I'm on a GCE instance with a postgresql DB and I'm running the following command:

```
COPY (Select * from mytable) TO '/home/myuser/myfile.txt' DELIMITER '#' CSV HEADER;
```

and getting the following error:

```
could not open file "/home/myuser/myfile.txt" for writing: Permission denied
```

how to fix it? (on my local machine this command works fine)

Comment: Did you search for it before ask this very popular question ?

Comment: @Houari yes I did, as well as read some of the answers here. I also worked around it by creating the file using nano and changing the chmod to 777 but the reason I'm asking is because there must be a better way to do it

Comment: In most of the case, a directory is created and used for copying to it from postgresql. with that way, you have to fix the permission problem only one time to this folder. Please look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28595245/1216680)

Comment: It looks like you probably want `\copy` not `COPY`. This is a FAQ.