# Postgres COPY TO not working for intended destination directory

Tags: postgresql, permissions, centos, copy, plesk

I have written a function that prepares data based on user-input from the web and copies the results down as a `csv` to a specified directory, from where the package (each request will contain information from 3 different tables/csv files) will be made available for the user to download.

The function itself works if the output directory is in the `pg_data` directory `/var/lib/pgsql/data/adc_downloads`, the permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 postgres postgres  4096 Dec  5 15:18 adc_downloads
```

But ideally I want the output directory to be here: `/var/www/vhosts/[vhostname]/httpdocs/adc_downloads`. After getting it to work in `pg_data`, I used `chown -R --reference=/var/lib/pgsql/data/adc_downloads /var/www/vhosts/[vhostname]/httpdocs/adc_downloads` and `chmod` with the same parameters to mimic the permissions which appears to have worked:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 postgres postgres  4096 Dec  5 14:19 adc_downloads
```

but I'm still getting a `Permission denied` error when trying to run the function with the intended output directory.

Something else then must be overriding the permissions I've (tried to?) set, any ideas what this might be? Given the function itself works in one directory but not another I don't think it's an [SELinux issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275602/postgresql-copy-command-giving-permissions-denied-error), though I may of course be wrong.

Version Info: `Postgres 8.4` `CentOS 6.5` built with `Plesk`.

Comment: note : the complete path ` /var/www/vhosts/[vhostname]/httpdocs/` upto `adc_downloads` must *at least* have an `x` bit for postgres (probably: as others)

Comment: Is [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75548/change-permissions-of-postgres-copy-to-exported-file) helpful?

Comment: @pirho no luck using the `chgrp` and `chmod` commands as suggested in the accepted answer

Comment: Can you paste minimal sample of the script that re-produces the error and the actual error message in whole? how do you run it? `psql`? Where do you run it?

Comment: @pirho fixed it, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this working (thanks to @joop's recommendation) in the intended location `/var/www/vhosts/[vhostname]/httpdocs/adc_downloads` by adding execute permission for the `other` users (including the `postgres` user) for the `[vhostname]` and `httpdocs` directories